# Set pm-suspend as default

Tags: 18.04, suspend, default, pm-utils

Because the command

```
systemctl suspend
```

doesn't work on my computer while

```
pm-suspend
```

apparently works correctly and the device enters sleep mode. I would like to make the last one as default, that is, when the computer automatically enters sleep mode, it executes pm-suspend instead of the systemctl command (which I think is the default in Ubuntu).

Some help? I have xubuntu bionic.